# how to get distinct result in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get distinct result of following table

```
id  | name   | created_on
1   | xyz    | 2015-07-04 09:45:14
1   | xyz    | 2015-07-04 10:40:59
2   | abc    | 2015-07-05 10:40:59
```

I want distinct **id** with latest **created_on**  means following result

```
1   | xyz    | 2015-07-04 10:40:59
2   | abc    | 2015-07-05 10:40:59
```

How to get above result by sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select id, name, max(created_on) as created_on from table group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select id,max(name), max(created_on) from table_name group by id
```

Additional Note:

As it appears, your table is not **normalized**. That is, you store the `name` along with `id` in this table. So you may have these two rows simultaneously:

```
 id  |  name  | created_on   
  1  |    a   |  12-12-12 
  1  |    b   |  11-11-11
```

If that state is not logically possible in your model, you should redesign your database by splitting this table into two separate tables; one for holding `id-name` relationship, and another to hold `id-created_on` relationship:

```
table_1 (id,name)
table_2 (id,created_on)
```

Now, to get last created_on  for each id:

```
 select id,max(created_on) from table_2
```

And if you want to hold `name` in the query:

```
 select t1.id, t1.name, t2.created_on from table_1 as t1 inner join
 (select id, max(created_on) as created_on from table_2) as t2
 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that id/name is always a pair:

```
select id, name, max(created_on)
from table
group by id, name;
```

It is safer to include both in the `group by`.  I also find it misleading to name a column `id` when it is not unique for the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword `DISTINCT` 
like

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```